# What's the difference between '...' and "..." in initialising a string?

Tags: fortran

So, I can initialize a string in Fortran with both

```
CHARACTER(LEN=4)::string
string = "jklm"
```

and

```
CHARACTER(LEN=4)::string
string = 'jklm'
```

What's the difference?

Comment: As a minor (perhaps trivial) point, there's no _initialization_ here, just _assignment_.  The important concept is in delimiting a character literal constant.

Comment: @francescalus thanks for clarifying. But I don't quite get your second sentence, even though I tried to translate. Do you mean to say that ... I only assign string to an already existing constant of format string ("jklm")?

Comment: `'jklm'` is what is known as a (character) _literal constant_.  It's a thing which just has, and always has, a value made up of those four letters.  Such a constant can be used in initialization, assignment, or in many other ways, and the interpretation of quote/apostrophe doesn't change that.  So, the delimiter (`"` or `'`) which tells the compiler "what follows here forms a string" and "what follows here is back to outside the string" isn't specific to initialization but to saying "constant".  [Hopefully that hasn't made things less clear...]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a glance of the fortan docs, it seems the same for the most part. Though if you plan to use a single quote within a string, use a double quote to enclose it.

```
// correct
"John's Stuff"

// wrong
'John's Stuff'
```

Alternatively:

```
// correct
'She said "Hey!"'
// wrong
"She said "Hey!""
```

http://www.fortran90.org/src/rosetta.html#strings-and-formatting

Edit: btw, same goes for most programming languages.

Comment: Also correct `'John''s Stuff'` and `"John""s Stuff"`, ie doubling the quotation mark or apostrophe.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark escape characters used to give me nightmares :)

Answer (score 2):

Functionally, they are the same. There is no difference at all although "" looks a little bit more readable.